# How to configure maven cargo to download deploy Wildfly 10 and add a test user?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, pom.xml

I found this setting on maven cargo:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>wildfly10x</containerId>
            <zipUrlInstaller>
                <url>http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip</url>
                <downloadDir>${project.basedir}/.cargo/downloads</downloadDir>
                <extractDir>${project.basedir}
                    /.cargo/extracts</extractDir>
            </zipUrlInstaller>
        </container>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-cargo</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this does not seem to work.

Can anyone provide me the correct configuration.

Also I want to add a user. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
<profiles>
        <!-- mvn clean package cargo:run -->
        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-standalone</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${cargo-maven2-plugin.version}</version>

                        <configuration>

                            <container>
                                <containerId>wildfly10x</containerId>
                                <zipUrlInstaller>
                                    <url>http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip</url>
                                </zipUrlInstaller>
                            </container>

                            <configuration>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.hostname>127.0.0.1</cargo.hostname>
                                    <cargo.jboss.management-http.port>9990</cargo.jboss.management-http.port>
                                    <cargo.servlet.users>testUser:admin1234!</cargo.servlet.users>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

To download and install the settings you need to run the following command:

```
mvn clean package cargo:run
```